# MySQL auto_increment при обращении и записи

Tags: mysql

Приветствую! Я так понимаю, увеличение на единицу при опции auto_increment происходит при любом обращении к таблице? а как сделать так, чтобы строки инкрементировались только при записи? Спасибо заранее)

Comment: Не..как они могли удаляться? я только двумя командами пользуюсь
SELECT и INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

В штатном случае `auto_increment` срабатывает только при добавлении новой записи, если значение первичного ключа не задано явно.

Если первичный ключ задается явно и устанавливаемое значение больше чем текущее значение `auto_increment`-а, то `auto_increment` пересчитывается (максимально значение + 1). Тоже самое происходит при обновлении значения `auto_increment`-ного ключа.

Comment: Я не задаю явно. Я только устанавливаю значение 1 в настройках базы.
The initial AUTO_INCREMENT value for table.

Comment: Задавать явно - это, если, например, есть таблица из двух полей (`id` и `name`). `id` - автоинкрементный ключ. И новая запись добавляется через:

    INSERT INTO (id, name) VALUE (1, 'Бла-бла-бла');

А неявно:

    INSERT INTO (name) VALUE ('Бла-бла-бла');

Или:

    INSERT INTO (id, name) VALUE (NULL, 'Бла-бла-бла');

Во втором и в третьем варианте вставки значение `id` установится автоинкрементом.

Comment: допустим я делаю так INSERT INTO (name) VALUE ('Бла-бла-бла');

инкрементируется

и так SELECT (id) FROM table
тоже инкрементируется. а можно сделать, чтобы в этом случае знаечение id не менялось?

Comment: @alexsher, сразу ряд вопросов возникает. Зачев вы тогда на это поле устанавливали автоинкремент? Почему нельзя использовать в качестве ключа какое-то другое поле, где автоинкремент не нужен? И вообще, абсолютно не обязательно, чтоб в каждой таблице было поле которое автоинкрементируется. Возможно, что для вашей задачи подойдет просто уникальное поле и в запросе использовать конструкцию [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: @alexsher можно подробнее, насчет инкремента при селекте )) ато я первый раз такое слышу. что именно инкрементируется?) инкремент - это увеличения значения колонки новой записи на 1 относительно последнего самого большого значения данной записи. каким образом и что у вас увеличивается при селекте?

Comment: Сейчас объясню) просто я 4-ый день работаю с базой))) еще не совсем освоил. В C#. я ище с конца таблицы, применяю DESC и после этого инкремент у меняпрыгает, допустим есть число 178, а следующее уже 1596 ( это я вижу в открытой таблице через Workbench

Comment: я ничего не понял) в любом случае: инкремент работает именно так, как я описал, и при селекте его по определению не может быть.

Comment: Тогда странно) почему номера идут не по порядку?))

Comment: Так всё работает, и меня смущают лишь номера. как то не эстетично получается)

Comment: нужно видеть структуру таблицы. возможно просто некоторые записи удалялись, авто инкримент запоминает последнее значение колонки, и дальше отталкивается уже от него,независимо от того, есть это запись в БД или уже удалена.